# How to count distinct Value in View

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

My query is

```
$sales = DB::table('sales')->select('id','customer_id','total','paid')->latest()->get();
```

And In my view I want to count the distinct customer_id

I used following line for that in view part.

```
{{$sales->distinct()->count('customer_id')}}
```

But it shows following Error:

> Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::distinct does not exist.

Comment: That issue is due to the fact that when you call `get` method on you query builder, It always return a `Illuminate\Support\Collection` Object, which doesn't have method define as `distinct` which is a method define in `Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder` Class. 

To solve that you have to use [`unique`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-unique) method which is define in `Collection`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be looking for unique():

```
{{ $sales->unique('customer_id')->count() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count your distinct() value like this:

```
$sales = DB::table('sales')->select('id','customer_id','total','paid')->distinct('customer_id')->count('customer_id')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```